# Citing multiple Japanese authors

Tags: citation-style

I'm trying to put a reference for article at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27894279 using APA format.

Is this the right way to do it?

Tadaka, E. Kono, A. Ito, E. Kanaya, Y. Dai, Y. Imamatsu, Y. and Itoi, W. (2016, November 28). *Development of a community's self-efficacy scale for preventing social isolation among community-dwelling older people (Mimamori Scale)*. Retrieved from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27894279

Comment: What is your doubt precisely? If the question is "is this citation correct", it is probably going to be closed as "too specific".

Comment: How is this specific to "Japanese authors"? The order of first and surnames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way according to [citethisforme](http://www.citethisforme.com):

Tadaka, E., Kono, A., Ito, E., Kanaya, Y., Dai, Y., Imamatsu, Y., & Itoi, W. (2016). Development of a community’s self-efficacy scale for preventing social isolation among community-dwelling older people (Mimamori Scale). *BMC Public Health, 16*(1). http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s12889-016-3857-4

One specific advise: If there is a DOI, **include the DOI** in the citation. Links are not persistent, DOIs are.